# In Vaadin 14's Uploader, how do I clear the previously uploaded files?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 14, I've used Vaadin Designer to add an Uploader component. It works fine.
However, I don't know how to clear previously uploaded files. I tried:

```
multiFileMemoryBuffer.getFiles().clear();
```

but it didn't do anything. Is there a way to clear the previously uploaded files from the Uploader component in Vaadin 14 when the component has been been created with Vaadin Designer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `upload.getElement().setPropertyJson("files", Json.createArray());` to clear the visual file representation on the client side. This was improved in V23 where you  can just call `upload.clearFileList();`